# When a string is not a string? Unicode normalization weirdness in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, firefox, unicode, unicode-normalization

I have run into what is, to me, some serious weirdness with string behavior in Firefox when using the [`.normalize()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) Unicode normalization function.

[Here](http://ruphus.com/unicodeNormalization.html) is a demo, view the console in Firefox to see the problem.

Suppose I have a button with an id of "NFKC":

```html
<button id="NFKC">NFKC</button>
```

Get a reference to that, easy enough:

```js
document.querySelector('#NFKC')
// <button id="NFKC">
```

Now, since this button has an id of NFKC, which we can get at that string as follows:

```js
document.body.querySelector('#NFKC').id
// "NFKC"
```

Stick that string in a variable:

```js
var s1 = document.body.querySelector('#NFKC').id
```

By way of comparison, assign the very same string to a variable directly:

```js
var s2 = 'NFKC'
```

So of course:

```js
s1 === s2
// true
```

And:

```js
s1 == s2
// true
```

Now’s the part where my head explodes.

To normalize a string, you pass one of `NFC`, `NFD`, `NFKC`, or `NFKD` to `.normalize()`, like this:

```js
'á'.normalize('NFKC')
// "á"
```

Of course, depending on the normalization form you choose, you get different codepoints, but whatever.

```js
'á'.normalize('NFC').length == 1
// true
'á'.normalize('NFD').length == 2
// true
```

But whatever. The point is, pass one of four strings corresponding to normalization forms to `.normalize()`, and you'll get a normalized string back.

Since we know that `s1` (the string we retrieved from the DOM) and `s2` are THE SAME STRING (`s1 === s2` is `true`), then obviously we can use either to normalize a string:

```js
'á'.normalize(s2)
"á"
// well yeah, because s2 IS 'NFKC'.
```

Naturally, `s1` will behave exactly the same way, right?

```js
'á'.normalize(s1)
 // RangeError: form must be one of 'NFC', 'NFD', 'NFKC', or 'NFKD'
```

Nope.

So the question is: why does it appear that `s1` is not equal to `s2` as far as `.normalize()` is concerned, when `s1 === s2` is true?

This doesn’t happen in Chrome, the only other browser I’ve tested so far.

**UPDATE**

This was a bug in Firefox and [has been fixed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1145326).

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: Why `s1` isn't === `s2`. I will make the question more obvious.

Comment: It might help if you can set up a demo that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I will set up a demo that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @Bergi Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qbxm49h2/1 An error is produced on the last test (`'á'.normalize(s1)`), in FF36.

Comment: @pat I'd say this is clearly not correct behavior; this looks like a pretty clear bug for the FF bug tracker.

Comment: I have added a bug report at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1145326

Comment: I found the [C++ implementation of `String.prototype.normalize` for Firefox](https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/js/src/jsstr.cpp#875). Looks like the problem is related to however `formStr` is set.

Comment: It's not just a DOM issue.  These also fail: `var s2 = 'NFKC'.split('').join('');` and  `var s2= 'NFKCabc'.replace('abc','');`.  But this doesn't:  `var s2= 'N'+'F'+'K'+'C';`.  Weird.

Comment: Node.id isn't in the mdn docs, or in the WHATWG [spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#node)

Comment: @cdosborn: [it is in that very spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-id) as well as [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id)

Comment: gah.. i was looking at the node api, right you are

Comment: Could you post your update as an answer and accept it? Congrats on finding this bug BTW!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will help, but the documentation states that

> This is an experimental technology, part of the Harmony (ECMAScript 6) proposal.
>   Because this technology's specification has not stabilized, check the compatibility table for usage in various browsers. Also note that the syntax and behavior of an experimental technology is subject to change in future version of browsers as the spec changes.

And the compatibility table is

```
Feature         Chrome  Firefox (Gecko) Internet Explorer           Opera   Safari
Basic support   34      31 (31)         11 on Windows 10 Preview    (Yes)   Not supported
```

However, the last update to this page was Nov 18, 2014.